# Justification of "be at odds"

Tags: idioms

> Two leaders remain **at odds** on how to resolve the crisis.

How do you reconcile this idiom to yourself? I myself imagine that two leaders are having a fight and *there are odds* on them at a bookmaker's, so they are *at odds*; when they stop fighting, you can no longer make a bet on them, so there are no odds.

Comment: I think this is effectively a matter of opinion. We could lay out the etymological history of a usage which originated almost five centuries ago, but for most people (native speakers *and* learners) this won't mean much in terms of *current* usage. FWIW, it might help OP to understand ***odds*** as meaning ***differences, inequalities***, but arguably that might make it more difficult to understand other idiomatic usages such as *"You can't **odds** it"* (meaning *"You can't **argue** with it"*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that native speakers *don't* reconcile idioms to themselves.  They learn them as fixed units, and unless they happen to think about it at some point, they never try to make sense of them.  If they *do* think about them, then there's no guarantee that two speakers will think about them the same way.

I have never thought about this phrase or come up with an explanation.  I know it the same way I know the meaning of the word "bread" without "reconciling" it; you can do the same.

As a matter of etymology, see the Oxford English Dictionary, which explains that the word came to mean "difference", possibly by association with the difference between odds and evens, and then from this "difference" meaning it came to specifically mean "disagreement, dissension, variance, strife" in the phrase *at odds*.  If that makes sense to you, then you can remember it that way.

Comment: When you don't live in a country that speaks one language, it is difficult to learn something in that language if it doesn't make sense to you. I feel like, If I can "explain" a phrase, I have a power over it. For me it is important to know, for example, that "at large" has a French origin "au large", meaning 'at liberty'. If I know it, more chances the phrase will stick to me.

Comment: @Graduate Do you find the final paragraph helpful at all?

Comment: Yes, now I translate the phrase to myself as "they remain at differences".

Comment: I've had a similar trouble with *[to come off](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198739/how-did-the-meaning-of-come-off-as-succeed-or-take-place-originate)*; It's really hard to use an idiom when there's no "feeling" for it. But with "at odds" there was no such problem for me for some reason.